# How to disable top bar in Unity?

Tags: unity

Is it possible to get rid of the top bar in Unity? It wastes screen space without any useful features in exchange. I would like to move "systray" area (where the date, power, sounds and gear menu resides) to the left panel, just below the application icons. Then, disable the top menu. How to achieve such setup?

Of course in such setup, applications' window menu must return from top bar to its parent window.

Comment: Using Gnome  (or [another DE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)) with a few extensions would be  *much* easier.... Unity has many features hardcoded in that makes even some small changes impossible without modifying the source and recompiling it...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but you need to hack source code. I tried it to isolate **unity dash** and embed it into **cairo dock**.

Grab source code from here

```
 bzr branch lp:unity/7.3
```

and follow this guide

http://glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=Cairo-Dock%20and%20Unity&lang=en